# how to compute weekly hours by days in data.table in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have a data.table days_dt

```
days_dt <- data.table(day = c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"))
```

which looks like

```
days_dt
day
1:    Monday
2:   Tuesday
3: Wednesday
4:  Thursday
5:    Friday
6:  Saturday
7:    Sunday
```

I have another single record data.table in which I have to and from times for each day :

```
 > weighted_average_time
  mon_from_time mon_to_time tue_from_time tue_to_time wed_from_time wed_to_time thu_from_time
 1      7.965174    21.39378      7.965174    21.39378      7.965174    21.39378      7.965174
  thu_to_time fri_from_time fri_to_time sat_from_time sat_to_time sun_from_time sun_to_time
 1    21.39876      7.965174    21.39876      7.942786    21.35149      9.766915    16.91617
```

I want to find day wise difference(in a new column) of to and from timings in the first table days_dt. example for monday (21.39378 - 7.965174 = 13.42861)

How to do this with data.table in R

the expected output must look like

```
days_dt
day     time_diff
Monday  13.42861
.       .
.       .
and so on for all the days
```

Comment: adding the expected output in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We `melt` the second dataset to `long` format, grouped by substring of 'variable' i.e. only the 'mon', 'tue', etc., get the difference of the 'value' column, and join `on` with the original dataset where the grouping column was created with `substr`

```
days_dt[, grp := tolower(substr(day, 1, 3))][]
days_dt[ melt(setDT(weighted_average_time))[,  diff(value) , 
     .(grp = sub("_.*", "", variable))], time_diff := V1, on = 'grp']
days_dt[, grp := NULL][]
#        day time_diff
#1:    Monday 13.428606
#2:   Tuesday 13.428606
#3: Wednesday 13.428606
#4:  Thursday 13.433586
#5:    Friday 13.433586
#6:  Saturday 13.408704
#7:    Sunday  7.149255
```